# Add sqlalchemy library to google app engine in pycharm

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-datastore, pycharm

I have following question to sqlalchemy in gae. I'm using the integrated **google app engine sdk** from **Pycharm**. Everything works fine, except the **integration of sqlalchemy**. The database itself works fine if I debug it with the Python interpreter. But when I'm trying to run it together with the google app engine I'm getting troubles with the import of the sqlalchemy library.

I already tried to solve it with virtualenv, but it didn't work either.

Here is my output log:

> Connected to pydev debugger (build 131.618)
>
> WARNING  2014-02-17 10:58:22,887 api_server.py:331] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
>
> WARNING  2014-02-17 10:58:22,895 simple_search_stub.py:1018] Could not read search indexes from c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\appengine.test\search_indexes
>
> INFO     2014-02-17 10:58:22,947 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: localhost:60878
>
> INFO     2014-02-17 10:58:22,994 dispatcher.py:171] Starting module "default" running at: localhost:8080
>
> INFO     2014-02-17 10:58:23,032 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: localhost:8000
>
> pydev debugger: process 4452 is connecting
>
> pydev debugger: process 4196 is connecting
>
> ERROR    2014-02-17 09:58:35,742 wsgi.py:262] 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
>       handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
>       handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
>       obj = **import**(path[0])
>
> File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test\main.py", line 16, in 
>       from bin.database.DBList import DBList
>
> File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test\bin\database\DBList.py", line 17, in 
>       from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
>
> ImportError: **No module named sqlalchemy**
>
> INFO     2014-02-17 10:58:36,410 module.py:617] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

So how is it possible to **add a third party library in gae**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to be expected because GAE has no idea what things your `virtualenv` is using. To mitigate this problem of using a third party library, all you need to do is download the source code of the library and all its dependents, and put it into a folder underneath your root project directory.

Add the folder to your `PYTHONPATH`, you can do this via:

```
import sys; sys.path.append('<your relative path to directory here>')
```

And then you are all set. By convention this directory that you put all your third party libraries under, is called `lib`.